# Monthly Compound Interest Java Application

Tags: java

I have to make an application that calculates the compound interest per month. The principal is $1000, and the rate is 2.65%. I have attempted to code the application and succeeded in some areas. However, I am having problems with the actual math and have tried different ways to get the compound interest with no success. The link is pasted below. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

http://pastebin.com/iVaWHiAJ

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class calculator{

private double mni, mni2, mni3;
private double intot = 1000;
private int a, c;

        double cinterest (int x){
                for(a=0;a<x+1;a++){
                        mni = intot * .0265;
                        intot = mni + intot;
                        //mni3 = (intot - mni) - 1000;
                        mni3 = (intot - mni);

                }
                return(mni3);
        }
}

class intcalc{

        public static void main(String[] args){

                calculator interest = new calculator();
                Scanner uinput = new Scanner(System.in);
                int months[] = {2, 5, 10, 500};
                int b;

                        for(b=0;b<4;b++){
                                System.out.println("Interest at " +
                                months[b] + " months is: " + interest.cinterest(months[b]));

                        }

        }

}
```

Comment: Hi there, please post code here, not on external link.

Comment: Please clarify the exact problem you're having. What problems are you having with the math?

Comment: it's not outputting the correct interest

Comment: Hi, try to use code conventions, take a quick look to page 10 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than that.  First of all, you can use Math.pow instead of doing a loop to do the compounding.  The simplest thing to do in this case is just use a static method:

```
public class CalcInterest{

  public static double getInterest(double rate, int time, double principal){
    double multiplier = Math.pow(1.0 + rate/100.0, time) - 1.0;
    return multiplier * principal;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int months[] = {2, 5, 10, 500};
    for(int mon : months)
        System.out.println("Interest at " + mon + " months is " + getInterest(2.65,mon,1000));

  }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
Interest at 2 months is 53.70224999999995
Interest at 5 months is 139.71107509392144
Interest at 10 months is 298.94133469174244
Interest at 500 months is 4.7805288652022874E8
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do some more reading on the math behind compound interest rates. [Here](http://math.about.com/library/weekly/aa042002a.htm) is a simple guide guide to calculating compound interest. After reading and understanding this you should make your `cintrest` code look something like -

```
double cintrest(int x){
    return intot - (intot(1+.0265)^x);
}
```

Im using your naming convention here, but you really need to make some better names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My teacher said it was suppose to look something like this.

Interest at 2 months is: $53.70
 
Interest at 5 months is: $139.71 

Interest at 10 months is: $298.94 

Interest at 500 months is: $478052886.52 

However, when I put in the method you posted I got this.

Interest at 2 months is: 53.0

Interest at 5 months is: 132.5

Interest at 10 months is: 265.0

Interest at 500 months is: 13250.0

Comment: @user2808631 Whoops, my bad. You need the compound interest formula, not one time interest. I updated my answer with a new link and new code.

Comment: Also, `^` doesn't do exponentiation.

Comment: @DennisMeng indeed, should be using Math.pow